# mongo c-driver bcon $ne value no equal

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to append a requirement to my BCON query where 'tribe_type' does not equal 'initial-public'.

My original code was and that worked:

```
 query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid));
```

When I add the second part, it compiles, however the mongo match fails.

```
        query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid),
            "{",
                "tribe_type",
                "$ne",
                "initial-public",
            "}"
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the BCON type for UTF-8 strings.
Be careful with implict $and's 
Be careful with nested documents and BCON.

```
    query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid),
        "{",
            "tribe_type",
            "$ne",
            "initial-public",
        "}"
    );
```

compiles into this command

```
 { "_id" : <an oid> }, { "tribe_type" : "$ne" }
```

which is obviously not what you want.

be explicit with the $and operation, correctly type the string as a UTF8 field, and make sure you capture the nested documents like this:

```
query = BCON_NEW (
                "$and", "[", "{", "_id", BCON_OID(&oid), "}",
                             "{", "tribe_type", "{", "$ne", BCON_UTF8 ("initial-public"), "}", "}","]"
                );
```

yields a query that looks like this

```
{ "$and" : [ { "_id" : <an oid> }, { "tribe_type" : { "$ne" : "initial-public" } } ] }
```

which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  While I did figure out a solution, yours is better and much more informative.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid),
            "tribe_type", 
                "{",
                    "$ne", BCON_UTF8 ("initial-public"),
                  "}");
```

Comment: I did post the fully working code after I figured it out.